# Java script getting unresponsive and stopping , due to huge data

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring-mvc, jboss

I ran into a weird issue , i have a drop down which is dynamically populated,when the record was around 500 it was fine ,but the record went beyond 1300 and the script went dead! ,
firstly there was an apostrophe used which caused the JS to go unresponsive removed that 
,now its working in chrome but Mozilla just makes it unresponsive.

> Any thoughts or solutions ?

Comment: is there any work around the script check in mozilla , the script is working infact just taking a while .

Comment: i think u have to use console.log for huge data

Comment: And i thought it was used for debugging ... i want to stop that "script is busy or unresponsive check" btw ...i do realize it's far fetched ,lot of misuse is possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

well the exact problem still persist , did a workaround 
instead of a java object in my jsp used JASON object instead. still slow as hell but the error wont pop up